# force pureconfig to generate ConfigReader for case classes

Tags: scala, scala-macros, pureconfig

I have a implicit class that wraps around a typesafe Config class to parse information from it.
This class uses pureconfig to parse the data out. I use this because I prefer `config.as[String]("foo")` instead of `loadConfig[String](config, "foo")`. But since I use this `HoconConfigUtil` as an adapter
all `case` classes I am trying to parse fails because the loadConfig method is not directly called on these
case classes. Because of this I am getting the error as shown below. What would be the best way to handle this issue?

**Error Message**:

`could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type pureconfig.ConfigReader[com.example.config.Parallelism]`

**implicit Adaptor class**

```
implicit class HoconConfigUtil(config: Config) {
    def as[T](path: String)(implicit derivation: Derivation[ConfigReader[T]]): T = {
      pureconfig.loadConfig[T](config, path) match {
        case Right(x: T @unchecked) => x
        case Left(th: ConfigReaderFailures) => throw makeException(th)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... since `T: ConfigReader` defines a context bound on `T`, your function also requires `implicit` evidence for `ConfigReader[T]` for any type `T`. Its similar to how something like a `List[A].sorted` requires an `Ordering[A]` evidence.

Comment: How about you remove `ConfigReader` context bound and handle the error in `Left` of your `loadConfig` result? Also, as far as I know pure-config does not auto-gen ConfigReader instances for your classes, so I think you will have to add those manually or write some macros.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh thanks for pointing out that context bound. I have removed it. it is not required.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh pure-config does generate ConfigReader for case classes right? that is what I am discussing here. How can I make pureconfig automatically generate the ConfigReaders for case classes using this model where my code does't directly call loadConfig on the case class.